# How to update a datagridview using vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

I am using the below mention code to update and delete data from datagridview. but i am unable to solve this issue. Delete is working but not update.

Public Sub CustomerUpdateBatch(ByVal dt As DataTable)

```
    Dim connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(Invoice.GetConnect())
    connection.Open()
    Try

        Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("Update_Customer", connection)
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        command.Parameters.Add("@C_ID", SqlDbType.Int, 16, "C_ID")
        command.Parameters.Add("@C_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "C_Name")
        command.Parameters.Add("@C_Address", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "C_Address")
        command.Parameters.Add("@C_Tel", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "C_Tel")
        command.Parameters.Add("@C_Fax", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "C_Fax")
        command.Parameters.Add("@C_Mobile", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "C_Mobile")
        command.Parameters.Add("@C_Email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "C_Email")
        command.Parameters.Add("@C_Tin", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "C_Tin")
        command.Parameters.Add("@C_Remarks", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "C_Remarks")
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        Dim delcommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("Delete_Customer", connection)
        delcommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        command.Parameters.Add("@C_ID", SqlDbType.Int, 16, "C_ID")

        Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter()
        adapter.UpdateCommand = command
        adapter.DeleteCommand = delcommand
        adapter.DeleteCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None
        adapter.Update(dt)

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        Throw
    Finally
        connection.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Does it error anywhere? Or just nothing happens? Does your stored proc work if you execute it through sql-server?

Answer (score 0):

One possible issue has to do with using auto-number indexes.  When you add new data to the table the index is not generated or picked up from the DB autmatically.  You don't say what database you have, but I'll show you an example for MySQL and for MS SQL.

First, you need to capture the events for the data adapter.  The "Connection" and "Dataadapter" definitions will need to be outside your function:

```
    Dim WITHEVENTS adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter()
```

Then you'll need to have a function to capture those events:

```
Private Sub myAdapter_RowUpdated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbRowUpdatedEventArgs) Handles adapter.RowUpdated
    If (e.StatementType = StatementType.Insert And e.Status = UpdateStatus.Continue) Then
        Dim id As ULong = getIdentity()
        If (id > 0) Then
            e.Row(0) = id
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The getIdentiy() function will need to be specific to your SQL server.  This one is for MySQL:

```
Public Function getIdentity() As ULong
        Dim newcommand As New MySqlCommand("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();", connection)
        Return newcommand.ExecuteScalar()
    End Function
```

Here is one for MS SQL:

```
Public Function getIdentity() As ULong
        Dim newcommand As New OleDbCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY", connection)
        Return newcommand.ExecuteScalar()
 End Function
```

Comment: He does in the tags. Sql-Server

Comment: True, but someone may have the same issue with MySQL and look, here is the answer in one place.